# How to print an array content within the `@Parameters` annotation in Junit

Tags: arrays, junit, parameters

I have a parametrized JUnit Class with something similar to this to setup the parametrized data:

```
@Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}/{1} : {2}")
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            {
                    "Samsung",
                    new Object[] { "size", "10" },
                    "http://my.test.service.com/svc/brand/samsung?size=10"
    },
            {
                    "Apple",
                    new Object[] { "color", "red" },
                    "http://my.test.service.com/svc/brand/apple?color=red"
    },
    // Code truncated

    });
}
```

After running the code, I can see the result like this:

```
[0: Samsung/[Ljava.lang.Object;@713dff89 : http://my.test.service.com/svc/brand/samsung?size=10]
[1: Apple/[Ljava.lang.Object;@23ab8f3f : http://my.test.service.com/svc/brand/apple?color=red]
```

etc...

This is quite logical as the second element `{1}` is an array.

Is there any way to get the content of the array?

E.g with a notation like

```
@Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}/{1[0]}-{1[1]} : {2}")
```

to get

```
[0: Samsung/size-10 : http://my.test.service.com/svc/brand/samsung?size=10]
[1: Apple/color-red : http://my.test.service.com/svc/brand/apple?color=red]
```

I tried to use `{1}{0}`, `{1[0]}` and  `{1.0}` but none are working

Answer (score 1):

The `name`-argument of the `Parameters` annotation is used as first parameter of a `MessageFormat.format(pattern, args...)` call.

I couldn't find a hint for formatting arrays in the javadoc of MessageFormat. My solution would be to add a fourth parameter to your list of parameters which contains the desired string.

```
Collection<Object[]> data = ... // build your data
for (Object[] parameter : data) {
    parameter[3] = Arrays.toString((Object[]) parameter[1]);
}
return data;
```